# Jquery button triggers form submit

Tags: jquery, forms, button, click

```
The following script enables users to prompt a value into the input field of a form:

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $('input[name="fine"]').val(computeEndTime($('input[name="ini"]').val()));
    });
    function computeEndTime(ini){
        var parts = ini.split(/[:,\s\.]+/).map(Number);
        var hourstart = parseInt(parts.shift());
        var minutestart  = parseInt(parts.shift());
        var totalm = (hourstart * 60) + minutestart + 100;
        var minutes = totalm%60;
        var hours = (totalm - minutes) / 60;
        return hours + ":" + minutes;
    }   
});
</script>
```

The HTML form is this:

```
<form action="next.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="ini" maxlength="5" />
    <input type="text" name="fine" maxlength="5" />
    <button>100</button>
    <input type="submit" name="invia" value="go on" />
</form>
```

As you can see, the script takes the time value typed into input `"ini"` and through the button prompts into input `"fine"` another time value (the initial one + 100 minutes).

The problem I am having is that when the button `<button>` is pushed, also the other submit button of the form is triggered, and the user is **immediately redirected to the page next.php**.

How can I avoid this, and require the user to push the submit button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the button to

```
<button type="button">100</button>
```

The default is `type="submit"`, so it submits the form.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
$("button").click(function(e){
   $('input[name="fine"]').val(computeEndTime($('input[name="ini"]').val()));
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Try not to use `button` as selector, this will trigger any button  which is in the document. Give it an identifier

Comment: Can you show me how to give the button an identifier and point to it in the script? If I had more than one `<button>`?

Comment: <button id="someId"></button> You would then select it with $("button#someId")

Comment: Great. Very Helpful.